# Automatically changing of script src when jekyll gist tag is used with private gist

Tags: javascript, github, jekyll, gist

I have a private gist and i want to embed that to my jekyll site hosted by github. But whenever i embed it using:

```
{% gist 931c1c8d465a04042403 %}
```

it automatically changes to:

```
<script src='https://gist.github.com/931.js?file=c1c8d465a04042403'> </script>
```

which produces no result.

I have tried it with public gist, for example:

```
{% gist 5555251 %}
```

and it changes to:

```
<script src='https://gist.github.com/5555251.js'> </script>
```

which produces the result. I have tried using:

```
<script src='https://gist.github.com/467f46c5cde7b2422ffe.js'> </script>
```

directly in my file and the result is seen in localhost but the github still doesn't show any result.

Please Help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the script tag has solved my problem. The problem was with my browser offline data. After, clearing everything from browser storage the gist is showing up in the github as well. Still i am confused why is

```
{% gist 931c1c8d465a04042403 %}
```

being changed to

```
<script src='https://gist.github.com/931.js?file=c1c8d465a04042403'> </script>
```

which is producing nothing.